# Handle same request multiple times

Tags: javascript, request, fetch-api

I'm building a silly music quiz game for learning. I need to populate my view with related music from [deezer api](https://developers.deezer.com/api).

What I need:

1. Get a random genre
2. Get 5 artist from this genre (id + name)
3. Get 1 music from each artist (name + link preview)

So, [I found my way](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Request) until step 3

But I can't find out how to properly send the same request 4 times (for each artist), and my reasearch gave me nothing so far

```
function deezer() {

    const reqGenero = new Request('https://api.deezer.com/genre');

    fetch(reqGenero)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Erro ao pegar gêneros');
            }
        })
        .then(generos => {
            /* pega genero aleatorio */
            var generoId = generos.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)].id;
            //console.log('\ngenero... ' + generoId);
            return fetch('https://api.deezer.com/genre/' + generoId + '/artists')
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Erro ao pegar artistas');
            }
        })
        .then(artistas => {
            /* 1 música de 4 artistas */
            var artistasIds = [];
            for(var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {   
                artistasIds.push(artistas.data[i].id);
                console.log('\nId: ' + artistasIds[i]);

                // CAN I SEND THIS REQUEST 4 TIMES?
                return fetch('https://api.deezer.com/artist/' + ids + '/top'); 
            }
        })         
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });      
}
```

*Pleade let me know if I'm doing something really wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using promises explicitly (see below for `async` functions), I'd probably approach it like this; see `***` comments for explanation:

```
// *** Give yourself a helper function so you don't repeat this logic over and over
function fetchJson(errmsg, ...args) {
    return fetch(...args)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { // *** .ok is simpler than .status == 200
                throw new Error(errmsg);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}
function deezer() {
    // *** Not sure why you're using Request here?
    const reqGenero = new Request('https://api.deezer.com/genre');
    fetchJson('Erro ao pegar gêneros', reqGenero)
        .then(generos => {
            /* pega genero aleatorio */
            var generoId = generos.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)].id;
            //console.log('\ngenero... ' + generoId);
            return fetchJson('Erro ao pegar artistas', 'https://api.deezer.com/genre/' + generoId + '/artists')
        })
        .then(artistas => {
            /* 1 música de 4 artistas */
            // *** Use Promise.all to wait for the four responses
            return Promise.all(artistas.data.slice(0, 4).map(
                entry => fetchJson('Erro ao pegar música', 'https://api.deezer.com/artist/' + entry.id + '/top')
            ));
        })         
        .then(musica => {
            // *** Use musica here, it's an array of the music responses
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });      
}
```

That's assuming you want to use the results in `deezer`. If you want `deezer` to *return* the results (a promise of the four songs), then:

```
// *** Give yourself a helper function so you don't repeat this logic over and over
function fetchJson(errmsg, ...args) {
    return fetch(...args)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { // *** .ok is simpler than .status == 200
                throw new Error(errmsg);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}
function deezer() {
    const reqGenero = new Request('https://api.deezer.com/genre');
    return fetchJson('Erro ao pegar gêneros', reqGenero) // *** Note the return
        .then(generos => {
            /* pega genero aleatorio */
            var generoId = generos.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)].id;
            //console.log('\ngenero... ' + generoId);
            return fetchJson('Erro ao pegar artistas', 'https://api.deezer.com/genre/' + generoId + '/artists')
        })
        .then(artistas => {
            /* 1 música de 4 artistas */
            // *** Use Promise.all to wait for the four responses
            return Promise.all(artistas.data.slice(0, 4).map(
                entry => fetchJson('Erro ao pegar música', 'https://api.deezer.com/artist/' + entry.id + '/top')
            ));
        });
        // *** No `then` using the results here, no `catch`; let the caller handle it
}
```

The `async` function version of that second one:

```
// *** Give yourself a helper function so you don't repeat this logic over and over
async function fetchJson(errmsg, ...args) {
    const response = await fetch(...args)
    if (!response.ok) { // *** .ok is simpler than .status == 200
        throw new Error(errmsg);
    }
    return response.json();
}
async function deezer() {
    const reqGenero = new Request('https://api.deezer.com/genre');
    const generos = await fetchJson('Erro ao pegar gêneros', reqGenero);
    var generoId = generos.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)].id;
    //console.log('\ngenero... ' + generoId);
    const artistas = await fetchJson('Erro ao pegar artistas', 'https://api.deezer.com/genre/' + generoId + '/artists');
    /* 1 música de 4 artistas */
    // *** Use Promise.all to wait for the four responses
    return Promise.all(artistas.data.slice(0, 4).map(
        entry => fetchJson('Erro ao pegar música', 'https://api.deezer.com/artist/' + entry.id + '/top')
    ));
}
```

Comment: typo `return fetch(...args)` should be `return fetch(args)` .

Comment: @AZ_ - No, it shouldn't. If you pass more than two arguments to `fetchJson`, we want to spread out the rest parameter when calling `fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 4 requests and wait for all of them to *complete*, using [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
.then(artistas => {
  /* 1 música de 4 artistas */
  const artistasPromises = artistas.data.map(artista =>
    fetch("https://api.deezer.com/artist/" + artista.id + "/top").catch(
      err => ({ error: err })
    )
  );
  return Promise.all(artistasPromises);
}).then(musicList => {
  console.log(musicList);
});
```

Notice the `catch()`. This makes sure that even if a fetch fails, the other fetch results are not ignored. This is because of the way [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) works. So, you need to iterate over `musicList` and check if there is any object of the shape `{ error: /* error object */ }` and ignore that while processing the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the statement

```
// CAN I SEND THIS REQUEST 4 TIMES?
return fetch('https://api.deezer.com/artist/' + ids + '/top');
```

with

```
const fetchResults = [];    
artistasIds.forEach(function(ids){  
  fetchResults.push(fetch('https://api.deezer.com/artist/' + ids + '/top'));
});
return Promise.all(fetchResults);
```

in *then* condition you'll get an array of values with top music from each artist. I haven't checked with the given API, but ideally it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make 5 requests (not 4 its 0-4) and wait for each to complete.
Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of request promises.(prefer over for- forEach and array.push)

and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
to wait for all the promises to get complete, which will return the array of resolved responses, if no failures.

```
.then(artistas => {
  /* 1 música de 4 artistas */
  var artistasIds = [];
  let ids = artistas.data.map(artist => artist.id).slice(0, 4);
  requests = ids.map(id => fetch(`https://api.deezer.com/artist/${id}/top`));
  return Promise.all(requests);
  }
})
```